# Is it possible to speed up the way mob spawners spawn mobs?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I think the title is pretty self descriptive but if it changes anything my goal is to spawn villagers. Does anyone know any commands or tactics to make the villagers spawn faster?

Comment: In MCJava you could edit its NBT. In MCBE the only method I (someone who hasn't ever played it) know to increase the rates is to transport the mobs away as fast as possible, but that changes nothing about the spawner itself.

Comment: To clarify, you need to use a mob-spawner right? you can't spawn the villagers with commands?

Comment: @CiurkitboyN Yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set up a command block on a Redstone clock with */tp ~ 1 ~* you can teleport the villagers to a different area which speeds up the spawn rate as there won't be as many villagers in one place.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that there is any way to speed up the spawn rate of mob spawners.

Here's a link on how spawners work in case you want to check out their mechanics.

https://minecraft.wiki/w/Spawner#Mechanics